# Can I drop an input tag holding a file onto a droppable zone?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, sahi

I am doing some front end testing using Sahi, and it's built in methods _setFile & _setFile2 are not flexible enough for the file uploading approach being used by the site. For this reason, I am wondering if I can add an input element to the browser and attach file elements and then execute a drag drop (via Sahi) to get the file elements passed to the droppable area. Does anyone know if it's possible to drag files from one browser input tag to another (or another viable approach)?

Comment: you can move populated file inputs around, but you can't populate the input (afaik) using code alone.

Comment: And by 'move around' it would apply any attached files to the droppable area?

Comment: what you can do is find the file dnd drop handler function(s) the page uses, and talk directly to those instead of relying on bound events. this might not be easy or possible to do programmatic if there are closures hiding the particular methods, but you can copy a chunk or two from the js file that defines them, and modify them to accept a blob as an argument instead of an event property. the idea is to intercept the part between the file drop and the ajax upload, and use your code to talk directly to the upload part using Blob()s or FormData() to spoof user-provided File() objects.

Comment: Yeah, that's the approach I'm currently taking. I overrided the addEventListener property of the HtmlDivElement in order to intercept the event listener assigned in a closure, but it seems like a hacky approach. I may just fork plupload and expose the listener myself...